# rdiff-backup is terribly slow when adding new files to the backup

Tags: linux, backup, rdiff-backup

For backing up my data I use `rdiff-backup` (2.0.5) on Ubuntu 20.10. The amount of data is only 127 GB but 80k Files / 17k Folders (mainly source code repositories, photos).

The problem I discovered is, that rdiff-backup seems to be terribly slow when adding new files. I wrote a bash script to demonstrate that (see below).

What the script does is:

- Generate 1000 empty files
- Do initial backup
- Generate another 1000 empty files
- Do another backup

While the inital backup takes roughly 1 second, the second one takes 7 seconds (detailed results below). This does not sound much but with my real life data I end up with several hours for very few new files.

What puzzles me is, that only the "real" time seems to explode. Does rdiff-backup get stuck with other processes?

I run the example on an internal ext4 SATA SSD.

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir src
mkdir dest

files=1000

printf "Creating some dummy files.\n"
for (( i=1; i<=$files; i++ ))
do
    touch "src/$i.txt"
done

printf "First run."
time rdiff-backup src/ dest/
printf "\n"
sleep 1

printf "Second run, nothing changed."
time rdiff-backup src/ dest/
printf "\n"
sleep 1

printf "Creating some more dummy files.\n"
for (( i=$files+1; i<=$files*2; i++ ))
do
    touch "src/$i.txt"
done

printf "Third run, adding new files to backup."
time rdiff-backup src/ dest/
printf "\n"
sleep 1

printf "Forth run, nothing changed."
time rdiff-backup src/ dest/
```

Output:

```
Creating some dummy files.
First run.
real    0m1,076s
user    0m0,869s
sys     0m0,157s

Second run, nothing changed.
real    0m0,511s
user    0m0,419s
sys     0m0,037s

Creating some more dummy files.
Third run, adding new files to backup.
real    0m7,460s       <--- 7 times longer!
user    0m1,374s
sys     0m0,310s

Forth run, nothing changed.
real    0m0,747s    
user    0m0,645s
sys     0m0,053s
```

Comment: Six hours is a ridiculous time. For comparison I can iterate across a couple of hundred GB over a WAN in about 2 minutes. Can you please include the command and/or configuration you're using. I suspect you're either over-thinking the configuration (one typical mistake is to specify checksum matches instead of time/size based ones) or simply missing an important element. Please also confirm the source _and_ destination filesystem types

Comment: The exact command is "rdiff-backup --print-statistics /media/oliver/Daten /media/oliver/9495e94c-ba49-4679-91ef-e39d3e0b56f9/Backup/Oliver/Daten/". The source file system is NTFS as it is a shared partition on a dual boot system. In fstab I use "UUID=5EE1FDE9634C1209 /mnt/data       ntfs    defaults,umask=000 0". The destination is ext4.

Comment: I believe the NTFS is the choke point. Also, you say these disks are both USB. But what protocol/connection speed?

Comment: The internal hard drive is connected through SATA2, the external by USB2.0. I will do a benchmark and backup the internal NTFS drive to SSD (ext4). Then backup from SSD to external drive. Maybe we can find the bottleneck this way.

Comment: Did some benchmarks (see above). It seems, that adding new files is terribly slow. I don't know why that should be the case.

Comment: I created a new backup from scratch, and now rdiff-backup is reasonably fast again.